# ¿Cómo controlar el evento MouseDown de un TextBlock en el code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos

Tengo un `ListBox` con `TextBlocks` como la lista:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
     <TextBlock Name="Address1" MouseDown="SongAddress"/>
     <TextBlock Name="Address2" MouseDown="SongAddress"/>
     <TextBlock Name="Address3" MouseDown="SongAddress"/>
     <TextBlock Name="Address4"  MouseDown="SongAddress"/> </ListBox>
```

Son 4 los `TextBlocks` que tiene el evento `MouseDown`. Y quiero diferente funcionalidad para cada uno. ¿Como podría controlar desde el `code-behind` cual de los 4 es presionado?

Comment: Ya que les has puesto nombre, puedes utilizarlo para distinguir cual es en el manejador del evento `MouseDown`

Answer (score 0):

El manejador de eventos en el código asociado a tu formulario tendrá más o menos esta forma:

```
    private void SongAddress_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

En este caso, el argumento `sender` te indica el control que ha lanzado el evento. Ahora lo único que tienes que hacer es comprobar el nombre del botón asociado al evento y llamar a la función adecuada:

```
    private void SongAddress_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { switch ((sender as TextBlock)?.Name)
            {   case "Address1":
                        TratamientoDelTextAddress1();
                    break;
                case "Address2":
                        TratamientoDelTextAddress2();
                    break;
                ...
            }
    }
```

Donde por supuesto, las funciones `TratamientoDelBotonXXXX` es donde irá tu código asociado.

El problema es que cuando cambies de nombre a cualquiera de los botones tendrás que cambiar también la etiqueta de este `switch` algo no demasiado recomendable. Puedes cambiar el código por esto:

```
    private void SongAddress_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { switch ((sender as TextBlock)?.Name)
            {   case nameof(Address1):
                        TratamientoDelTextAddress1();
                    break;
                case nameof(Address2):
                        TratamientoDelTextAddress2();
                    break;
                ...
            }
    }
```

Donde `nameof` es una función nueva de C# 6.0 que te devuelve el nombre de un elemento o propiedad. En este caso, si cambias el nombre de un cuadro de texto, el compilador te avisará con un error y podrás modificar el código sin problema (no estoy seguro de si VS para WPF hace el cambio de nombre automáticamente).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Totalmente funcional, fue de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres hacer dinámicamente, puedes ligarlos con el operador += y crear los métodos con el snippet. Sin embargo, he visto que en el Visual Studio, por alguna razón, cuando asignas un nombre de un elemento, no te aparece disponible en el intellisense del code-behind hasta que cierras y vuelves a abrir nuevamente el IDE completo.

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues un ejemplo, para hacer mas clara tu respuesta